# Node.js/JS converting standard windows paths to useable file path for CLI application

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, escaping

I am very new to node and JavaScript, but I have a simple Node.js CLI application working that extracts images from Photoshop .PAT files and saves them to a specified directory.

I've noticed that in order for the paths that I pass in as arguments (`input_pat` for the input .pat file, and `output_dir` for the destination directory) they must either use forward slashes, or double backslashes or Node freaks out.

What I want to be able to do is this:

`node save.js "C:\patterns\library.pat" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\pat-parser-master\src\save\"`

Is there a way to convert standard windows path notation into a format that javascript will accept? I.E. replacing all backslashes with forward slashes, or doubling up the backslashes?

Must I always use double backslashes or forward slashes when passing in paths?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try whether removing the quotes makes a difference (since there are no spaces in your paths) but I'm afraid either of the two working alternatives is what you need to use.

Comment: So I guess when using node I just have to get used to using forward slashes or double backslashes? It kind of triggers my OCD that I can't just use standard windows path notation.

Comment: If I run a program that contains just `console.log(argv)` like `node jay.js c:\tmp` the output has double backslashes in the path like `C:\\tmp` which means it can be used as file path as-is. In other words, you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. How exactly did you notice this? Can you show relevant code and the error message you got?

Comment: I am using this: https://github.com/jardicc/pat-parser

save.js:
https://gist.github.com/visusys/043485bea0d7c46fd73f981372ca4c94

main.js:
https://gist.github.com/visusys/2873bdae82675704a92b9811845983d5

My command:
`C:\Users\futur\Desktop\pat-parser-master\src>node save.js "True Grit Atomica-Ink-Effects.pat" "C:\Users\futur\Desktop\pat-parser-master\src\save\"`

Error:



`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\futur\Desktop\pat-parser-master\src\save"pat_0_all_Atomica - Ink Viscosity _NONE_8_alpha-true_RGB_.png'`

If I use forward slashes, all is well.

Comment: The problem is line 100 in main.js; it doesn't use path.join() to create the output filename but simply adds strings together. You need to also remove the quotes around the save dir and node won't interpet `\"` as `"`.